# Change style after data binding

Tags: angular

I was trying to change css styles of ion-textarea after data binding but I couldn't find the right way.

html file

```
<ion-textarea id='headline' placeholder='{{ "CREATE.TITLE" | translate 
     }}' [(ngModel)]='contentTitle' 
          (input)="autoSizeDescription($event);"></ion-textarea>
```

ts file

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("ion-textarea");
for (var i = 0 ; i < elems.length ; i ++) {
  var textArea: any = <HTMLElement>elems[i];
  textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  textArea.style.height     = 'auto';
  textArea.style.height     = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

By data-binding, textArea is filed with some texts and I need to resize textarea to show full texts.
This code works when I add some texts on textarea but I need to show full texts on initial step.
Is there anyway to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can conditionally add a css class to the ion-textarea element using *ngClass* if the contentTitle variable is not empty.

Comment: I need to calculate height manually so adding ngClass doesn't help me.

Comment: what about NgStyle? https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: it doesn't work either. 
Is there any way to check if the data-binding was finished or not?

Comment: Could you try running the function inside a setTimeout after initializing contentTitle variable.

Comment: You shouldn't be using document.getElementsByTagName.  Use @ ViewChild or @ ViewChildren and access the element through that. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: I just tried it but not working.
Is it possible to trigger keyboard event to the ion-textarea manually?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm using Ionic 4*

Use **@ViewChildren** or **@ViewChild** (if only one input element) and **ionViewDidEnter**.

First update your html with **#growingTextArea** on your **ion-textarea** element. You are supposed to be able to target the element by name but this wasn't working for me.

```
 <ion-textarea 
    #growingTextArea 
    id='headline' 
    placeholder='{{ "CREATE.TITLE" | translate }}' 
    [(ngModel)]='contentTitle'
    (input)="autoSizeDescription($event);">
  </ion-textarea>
```

Then

```
export class App {
    @ViewChildren("growingTextArea") ionTextAreas: QueryList<TextInput>
    // ..or
    @ViewChild("headline") headlineTextArea: TextInput

    ionViewDidEnter() {
      this.ionTextAreas.forEach(textArea => {
        //debugger;
        this.adjustTextBox(textArea._native.nativeElement);
      });
    }

    autoSizeDescription(event: any): void {
       this.adjustTextBox(event.target);
       return;
    }

    private adjustTextBox(target: any) {
       target.style.overflow = 'hidden';
       target.style.height = 'auto';
       target.style.height = target.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
 }
```

If you are using a newer version of Ionic then you may need to adjust the code selecting the native text area element in the **ionViewDidEnter()**.  This line -> **textArea._native.nativeElement**. Just add a **debugger;** line to the foreach loop in the **ionViewDidEnter** and inspect the element to find how to get to the native textarea element.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/textarea#methods

References:

https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. but it didn't work.
 Is it possible to trigger keyboard event to the ion-textarea manually?

Comment: Can you share more of your component code? Like the autosizeDescription() function?

Comment: sure.
protected autoSizeDescription(event: any): void {
  let textArea: any  = event.target;
  textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  textArea.style.height  = 'auto';
  textArea.style.height  = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
  return;
}

Comment: Are you calling a web-service and then updating contentTitle?

Comment: I don't call a webservice

Comment: Instead of AfterViewInit try using the Ionic life cycle hook ionViewDidEnter.

Comment: The other thing that could be happening is the event.target passed to autoSizeDescription(event: any) is pointing to the actual html textarea whereas the @ViewChild will be pointing to the ion-textarea.  There is a way you can traverse to the child textarea element located in the ion-textarea.  I will have to try it on my end and get back to you.